# Magento. How to reset Checkout Quote reserved Id?

Tags: session, magento, reset, quote

Due to an integration with an external system during the checkout I need to reset & provide a new `reservedId` for the current quote in some situations. I’ve tried several methods, with no success

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Or, at least, if this is not possible, how can I reset the whole Chekout session without forcing the customer to logout?
I’ve tried with `unsetAll()`, `clear()` & `resetCheckout()` methods at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session`, but they don’t seem to do the trick

Comment: Hmm, did you try something like `setReservedId(null)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Zyava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320733/zyava) has suggested, just doing `setReservedOrderId(null)` did it...

I had tried that previously, but problem was (I think) I was doing that inside the Javascript controller flow
Now I am just placing there a flag as a new session variable & just breaking the process with

```
$this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
return;
```

Then, when coming back to Checkout, if the flag is set, making...

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null);
```

Did the trick & Magento creates a new reservedOrderId for the quote

Comment: You should accept your own answer as correct to help other SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi there, I 'm trying to do something similar. Since I have an integration with a third party payment gateway, once if the payment fails for  any reason I need to save the order with a pending_payment status and redirect them to cart page with error message at the top. But I also want to keep the cart filled. But since the quote is getting saved into an order, I'm not able to retain the cart.

Comment: And say if I throw an exception, the reserved order id remains the same and when the customer corrects his details and tries again, it does not let them proceed cuz the external payment gateway always needs a new order id. Is it possible that I can throw an exception for the first time when the payment fails and then `setReservedOrderId(null)` so that when they correct their details and try again the order goes fine this time

Comment: If you place `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null);` at the top of checkout onepage initial template then you can throw the exception & redirect user to cart. Then, when usaer starts again checkout process the quote order_id will be reseted

Answer (score 1):

Like Raul said, placing `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null);` at the top of the checkout page resets the `reserved_order_id`. But, in order to remain null you have to save the quote.
So, the code would be `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setReservedOrderId(null)-save();` It worked for me on Magento CE 1.7.